# Implantação só funciona com smartphone samsung j5 plugado no computador

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Só consigo fazer implantação, quando o meu cel está plugado no meu note. Se eu usar o padrão(`VisualStudio_android-23_arm_phone(Android 6.0 - API23)`), não funciona. Build com êxito, mas a implantação com falhas. Não sei o porque disso. Não testei com outros modelos. No meu Visual só vem essa opção(`VisualStudio_android-23_arm_phone(Android 6.0 - API23)`).Não consigo carregar outra opção no VS e nas configurações do projeto Android(Meu projeto é Cross Platform), eu usei como target version a `Lollipop(Android 5.1 API 22)`.
Minha configuração Android:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu App.xaml.cs

```
namespace Teste2
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //MainPage = new Teste2.MainPage();
            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Teste2.MainPage());
        }

        protected override void OnStart()
        {
            // Handle when your app starts
        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
            // Handle when your app sleeps
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            // Handle when your app resumes
        }
    }
```

E meu MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

Meu MainPage.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Teste2"
             x:Class="Teste2.MainPage">

    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
        <StackLayout Padding="5,5,0,0">
            <Label Text="Adicionar um Produto" TextColor="Green" />
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout Padding="10,0,10,0">
            <Entry x:Name="txtNome" Placeholder="Nome do produto" HorizontalOptions="Start" 
                    VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="300" FontSize="Small"/>
            <Entry x:Name="txtCategoria" Placeholder="Categoria do produto" HorizontalOptions="Start" 
                    VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="300" FontSize="Small" />
            <Entry x:Name="txtPreco" Placeholder="Preço do produto" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" 
                    HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="300" FontSize="Small" />
            <Button HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HeightRequest="40" Text="Adicionar/Atualizar Produto" 
                    Clicked="btnAdicionar_Clicked" FontSize="Small"/>
        </StackLayout>

        <!--<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="10,5,10,0">
            <ListView x:Name="listaProdutos" ItemSelected="listaProdutos_ItemSelected" BackgroundColor="Aqua" SeparatorColor="Blue">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                                <MenuItem Clicked="OnAtualizar" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" Text="Atualizar" />
                                <MenuItem Clicked="OnDeletar" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" Text="Deletar" IsDestructive="True" />
                            </ViewCell.ContextActions>
                            <StackLayout Padding="10,10" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label Text="{Binding Nome}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Categoria}" TextColor="Blue" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Preco}" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>-->
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

**EDIT1**

Lendo os warnings gerados, diz que há um conflito de versão dos pacotes instalados. Tentei instalar os pacotes, que me foi sugerido na aba atualização do NuGet e está dando esse problema. O interessante que antes me pediu esse pacote: `Microsoft.Bcl.Build` e instalei e ao fechar e abri o VS, a referência sumiu, porem o pacote se encontra na pasta Package(caso 1).
Instalando os demais, não deu conflito na instalação, mas quando executo a aplicação, vem o conflito(caso 2).

Dessa forma a implantação com o AVD default não funciona, mas se eu conectar o meu cel funciona.

**EDIT2**

Essa é mensagem que dá quando eu rodo. Ele builda normalmente, mas na implantação dá pau e a mensagem é apenas um warning:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**EDIT3**

Atualizei a versão de destino(já havia feito isso) e deu agora esse warning e nada de implantação:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Onde eu vejo o log de build? Mas se for o meu cel conectado(Samsung j5), aí funciona, mas não consigo visualizar os componentes inseridos no projeto.

Comment: Resolvi deixar a execução por muito tempo, e depois de uns 8 minutos, veio a mensagem que o Android não está respondendo. Deseja para ou continuar? Deixei continuar. Se eu estou ouvindo música, enquanto está o App executando, não consigo parar a música, passar para a próxima, nada. O controle fica todo com o App, mas a música não para e ao terminar a próxima executa normalmente. Estou escrevendo isso, apenas como subsídio para a resolução desse problema.

Comment: A pergunta havia recebido um voto e agora ficou sem. Não acredito que o colega que votou, removeu o voto. Dias atrás discordei de dois colegas aqui no site e desde então, coincidência ou não, todas as minhas perguntas têm recebido downvote, independente se a pergunta está ou não, dentro das regras. Coisa miúda essa.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que você não deva se preocupar muito com esses Warns, pois parece que é problema de compatibilidade desse ADV com o seu computador.

Tenta usar o emulador android x86 (https://www.visualstudio.com/pt-br/vs/msft-android-emulator/?rr=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com.br%2F). Ou algum outro como o https://www.genymotion.com/